# Texts on the History of Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

I thought I hated math at first, but linear algebra really changed my outlook on mathematics. What I really didn't like was calculus, which is fine, there are plenty of folks who would love to focus on purely calculus.

My question is whether there is a comprehensive history of linear algebra?

The only two sources I've found of note is a [link to a pdf from University of Utah](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/s2012/2270/web-projects/christensen-HistoryLinearAlgebra.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj-_NOSwM7LAhUE2WMKHZBrBeUQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHSjZEXti6ewFd08aRvkWaRK9VQmQ&sig2=9HqY3R5KvTQHbYYX4aUpdw) and this book called [The Chinese Roots of Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801897556)

Does anyone else know of anymore?

Comment: Please consider posting on the history of math and science board

Comment: I didn't know that board existed.

Comment: It does yes ! Take a look

Comment: Take a look at Chapter 5 of A History of Abstract Algebra by Israel Kleiner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105732/references-on-the-history-of-linear-algebra. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62318/origin-of-the-dot-and-cross-product/62332#62332 and http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/267/books-on-the-history-of-linear-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roger Hart (the author of the book you mentioned) has a web site here: http://www.rhart.org/algebra/